# MySQL - Use primary key values to get corresponding values from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a few MySQL tables with data about concerts. Here are the relevant fields from the Artists and Shows tables:

```
----------------------  --------------------
| Artists            |  | Shows            |
|--------------------|  |------------------|
| ArtistID (PK)      |  | ShowID (PK)      |
| ArtistName         |  | ArtistID (FK)    | <--- references Artists(ArtistID)
|                    |  | OpenedForID (FK) | <--- also references Artists(ArtistID)
----------------------  --------------------
```

I've written this query that lists each opening band and the band that they opened for:

```
select ArtistName, OpenedForID
from Artists, Shows
where Shows.ArtistID = Artists.ArtistID
and OpenedForID != 999;
```

...which gives the following result:

```
------------------------------
| ArtistName   | OpenedForID |
|----------------------------|
| Small Band A | 4           |
| Small Band B | 5           |
| Small Band C | 6           |
------------------------------
```

What I want, and don't know how to do, is to show the ArtistName in the second column instead of the OpenedForID. So, use the value of the FK Shows.OpenedForID, which references Artists.ArtistID, to get the corresponding ArtistName. I've been looking around here for answers all morning but had no luck. I'm a bit sick today so I'm probably missing something obvious.

The end result should look more like this:

```
--------------------------------
| ArtistName   | OpenedFor     | 
|------------------------------|
| Small Band A | Larger Band D |
| Small Band B | Larger Band E | 
| Small Band C | Larger Band F | 
--------------------------------
```

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) Years`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

As you have two references, join another Artist table.

But use JOINs they are now around for 30 Years, and should always be used, no exeption

```
select a1.ArtistName, a2.ArtistName
from Artists a1
JOIN Shows s ON s.ArtistID = a1.ArtistID
JOIN Artists a2 ON s.OpenedForID = a2.ArtistID 
WHERE s.OpenedForID != 999;
```

Comment: sorry typo in my answer. i have seen that you give the same answer one minute earlier. So will delete my